# counting character values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

i have a Dataframe which is like this:

```
teammember <- c('Member A', 'Member B', 'Member C')
value_a <- c('success', 'fail', NA)
value_b <- c('fail', NA, 'success')
value_c <- c('success', NA, 'fail')

data_df <- data.frame(teammember, value_a, value_b, value_c)
```

Now i want to count each 'success' grouped by the team member. My idea was something like this:

```
data_df %>%
  group_by(teammember) %>% 
  filter(value_a == "success" | value_b == "success" | value_c == "success") %>% 
  summarise(sales = length(value_a) , length(value_b) , length(value_c)) %>% 
  select(teammember, sales)
```

My result is looking like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
teammember sales
<fct>      <int>
1 Member A       1
2 Member C       1
```

But it shoul look like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
teammember sales
<fct>      <int>
1 Member A       2
2 Member C       1
```

Can you enlighten me what the right solution should look like? :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Constantin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were counting `success` for each column with `summarize`, while what you want is the number of `successs` in each row. You can try `rowSums`:

```
res <- data.frame(
    teammember = data_df$teammember,
    sales = rowSums(data_df[, paste0('value_', letters[1:3])] == 'success', na.rm = T)
)
#   teammember sales
# 1   Member A     2
# 2   Member B     0
# 3   Member C     1
```

rows with zero values can be removed with `res <- res[res$sales > 0, ]`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `filter_at` in the beginning, then `gather` the 'value_' column into 'long' format, `filter`the 'val having "success" string and get the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_df %>%
    filter_at(vars(matches("value")), any_vars(. %in% 'success')) %>% 
    gather(var, val, value_a:value_c, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    filter(val =='success') %>% 
    count(teammember)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  teammember     n
#   <fctr>     <int>
#1 Member A       2
#2 Member C       1
```

---

Or another option would be to do a `nest`ing and then with `map` we get the count

```
library(purrr)
data_df %>% 
  nest(-teammember) %>%
  transmute(teammember, sales = map(data, ~ sum(unlist(.x) == "success", na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  filter(sales != 0)
#   teammember sales
#1   Member A     2
#2   Member C     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This is very helpful!